# Rmarkdown automatically use function on plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I'm producing an RMarkdown document where each chunk produces a plot.

For each of these plots, I'd like to apply a special formatting function that adjusts the way the title appears.

Is there a way to tell `knitr`/`rmarkdown` to apply this special function to each chunk's plot? For example, maybe there's a chunk option like `{r, fig.function = adjust_title_position}`?

The motivation is that I don't want to have to retype the function call separately for each plot (e.g. `adjust_title_position(plot_42)`) and, at the same time, I don't want to use something like `lapply(my_plots, adjust_title_position)` which would require all the plots to be defined in one place.

Below is a minimal example of the RMarkdown file to which this could be applied.

````
---
title: "RMD_Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# Define helper function
  adjust_title_position <- function(p) {
    # Shift the horizontal position of the plot title
    p_built <- invisible(ggplot2::ggplot_build(p))
    gt <- invisible(ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(p_built))
    gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(2, max(gt$layout$r))

    # Prints the plot to the current graphical device
      gridExtra::grid.arrange(gt, newpage = TRUE)
    # Invisibly return the gtable object  
      invisible(gt)
  }

```


```{r plot_1}
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  labs(title = "Weights and miles-per-gallon")
```

```{r plot_2}
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Sepal length and width")
```
````

Comment: I think you would want to look into Knitr's [output hooks](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) - there's a `plot` hook that you could modify to do this.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot control the generating process through the plot hook. You can adjust the way the plot itself is included on the HTML canvas or in your pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reregister the `print`-method for `ggplot`-objects.

```r
# Define helper function
adjusted_title_position <- function(p) {
  # Shift the horizontal position of the plot title
  p_built <- invisible(ggplot2::ggplot_build(p))
  gt <- invisible(ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(p_built))
  gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(2, max(gt$layout$r))

  # Prints the plot to the current graphical device
  gridExtra::grid.arrange(gt, newpage = TRUE)
}

# Reregister print.ggplot
assignInNamespace("print.ggplot", adjusted_title_position, asNamespace("ggplot2"))
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. I wish it was possible to just use some `knitr` or `rmarkdown` option, but this seems like the best solution outside of that. Thanks @crsh!